# Make list of arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am making a neural network in Python and I want to generate training data for it. I need to make list of arrays.

I tried turning the `arrays` into `lists`. I tried the `numpy.append()` function and nothing worked.

Comment: Show the complete code what you tried and errors if any.

Comment: https://github.com/SnailingGoat/CODEFOR_STACKOVEFLOW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final_array = array_camera.append(TD_camera)
final_direction = array_direction.append(TD_direction)
```

The above 2 lines doesn't work the way you expect.

**append()** function of list doesn't return anything. It adds data at the end of the list object through which the append() was called.

So final_array & final_direction will be None.

I think you just need to append data to final_array & final_direction. Like this

```
final_array ,final_direction =[],[]
.....
.....
final_array.append(TD_camera)
final_direction.append(TD_direction)
```